# How to get button id and extract a part of it?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Table has many similar buttons. Each of them has different id number. By using Selenium IDE 2.5 I can place these buttons at the top left corner cell of table. I can press that button with selenium by using button class. The thing is - I need that button id number. Can I extract and store it?
For example, particular button id is `SYS01_666` and button class is `spark-InfoButton`.
I need to extract numbers "666" and store it by locating button by it's class. Is it possible?

I'm not sure if it is clear, what is my problem, because I am not a programmer.

Comment: I posted my reply, then realized that my code is for Selenium WebDriver. Not Selenium IDE :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the id of the button in a variable(eg. ButtonId) using storeAttribute command.
And then to perform any sort of extraction operations on the variable use

Command : store ||
Target : javascript{storeVars['ButtonId']}.substr(x,y) ||
Value : a different variable to store the extracted text